# how to put a incremental footnote number inside square brackets in latex, where footnote is converted into endnote

Tags: footnotes, hyperlink, endnotes

I am trying to make endnotes appear in the text as [1] , [2] .... with hyperlink to the text at the end of the document.
When I try to do it with footnote by following code, the appearance is correct [1], but they appear as footnotes on the same page.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,autolang=other,bibencoding=inputenc,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{A footnote}

\end{document}
```

but when I convert it to the endnote using following code, the hyperlink and their defined formatting disappears.

```
\usepackage{enotez} 
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\let\footnote=\endnote
```

[image]

I want it to be like this

[image]

How to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enotez package has a lot of options; I recommend reading [its documentation](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enotez/enotez_en.pdf).

In particular, it has a `mark-cs=` option you can use to provide a command to format the marks. The command should take one argument. Here I define a command `\newcommand{\bracketme}[1]{\,[#1]}` that puts its argument in brackets, preceded by a narrow space (`\,`) and set this to the value of `mark-cs=`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,autolang=other,bibencoding=inputenc,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{enotez} 
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\let\footnote=\endnote
\newcommand{\bracketme}[1]{\,[#1]}
\setenotez{mark-cs={\bracketme}}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{A footnote}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: enotez example]

I think this is a long the lines of what you're looking for, but can be tweaked.

If you want links to be blue for example, you can use `\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}`, or to just make these blue, use `\textcolor{blue}{[#1]}` in the command (which requires the `xcolor` package or similar).

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your guidance @frabjous